# Multiple views with different contexts for the same route in Pyramid

Tags: python, pyramid

I've created a simple application to reproduce the issue I'm experiencing:

```py
from pyramid.config import Configurator


def main(global_config, **settings):
    def view(request):
        pass

    class Dummy:
        pass

    def dummy_factory():
        return Dummy()

    with Configurator(settings=settings) as config:
        config.add_route("dummy.route", r"/dummy/route", factory=dummy_factory)
        config.add_view(view, route_name="dummy.route", context=Dummy)
    return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

If check list of routes then you can see that no one view registered for that route:

```
$ env/bin/proutes development.ini
Name           Pattern         View         Method    
----           -------         ----         ------    
dummy.route    /dummy/route    <unknown>    *
```

If remove `context` parameter from `add_view` call then everything works as expected. But in my real application I need to have more than one view for the same route but with different contexts. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP misinterpreted program output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually everything works well! I was confused with output of `proutes` command.